# How to download jpg/doc file from my server with Url in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is unable to download file from sever

My code work fine for any Google image-url (eg.:-http://blogs.independent.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/google-zip.jpg)

but it is not work in case of my server image-url("eg.:-[http://110.15.445.87/xyz/abc/123.jpg]")

i dont know where is problem

my code is :-

```
     //Create a stream for the file
    Stream stream = null;

    //This controls how many bytes to read at a time and send to the client
    int bytesToRead = 10000;

    // Buffer to read bytes in chunk size specified above
    byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];


    // The number of bytes read
    try
    {
        String Url = "http://112.196.32.51/ll1/UploadFiles/13062402231250.jpg";
        //String Url = "http://blogs.independent.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/google-zip.jpg";
        //Create a WebRequest to get the file
        HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);

        //Create a response for this request
        HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();

        if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
            fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;

        //Get the Stream returned from the response
        stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();

        // prepare the response to the client. resp is the client Response
        var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        //Indicate the type of data being sent
        resp.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        String fileName = "Rock.jpg";
        //Name the file 
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());

        int length;
        do
        {
            // Verify that the client is connected.
            if (resp.IsClientConnected)
            {
                // Read data into the buffer.
                length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

                // and write it out to the response's output stream
                resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                // Flush the data
                resp.Flush();

                //Clear the buffer
                buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
            }
            else
            {
                // cancel the download if client has disconnected
                length = -1;
            }
        } while (length > 0); //Repeat until no data is read
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            //Close the input stream
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do u get an error message?

Comment: Instead of writing all the code yourself, why don't you just do a 301 redirect to the image url and let the asp.net engine handle the response content type?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter sir,save/open dialog box not open in my severurl case.